# Replace occurrences of the pipe delimiter inside an XML tag in R

Tags: r, xml

I have a text file with embedded XML content. The fields are separated by "|" but there are some values separated by pipe inside xml tags.I want to replace the pipe separator inside the xml tags with white space.

A few rows of the data:

```
TASK_VIEWED_FLAG|TASK_OUTCOME|CURRENT_QUEUE|QUEUE_CHANGE_TS|
TASK_XML_DATA|SCORE_XML_DATA|
"N"|" "|"4"|"."|"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tasks xmlns="xyz.com/abc/wkbh/task"><task><taskxml>"|
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scores xmlns:dnr="xyz.com/abc/wkbh/score"><score><scorexml>
<Params>score_var=26.0|perc_var=76.5|prop_var=0.74</Params>
<weight>w1=3.0|w2=7.0</weight>"
```

The below attempt is messing up the headers.

```
newtext <- readLines("sample.txt")
newtext <- gsub(">(.+?)|(.+?)|(.+?)<", ">\\1[[:space:]]\\2[[:space:]]\\3<", newtext)
```

Any hints on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: I know of no automated way of dealing with a non-standard file format like this. If there were an easy way for you to determine that a newline was mid-xml-string, then you could escape them and then parse as a pipe-delimited file, but otherwise you may need a tokenizer for this.

Comment: From my experience, using regular expressions for trying to handle this was fraught with peril and problem. Regex is not perfectly suited for tokenizing. (https://xkcd.com/1171/)

Comment: @r2evans - My data size is greater than 2 GB. So, it is feasible to use a tokenizer on this data?

Comment: @Parfait - The data is received from a third party firm so might be a little difficult to request for a change. So, I was wondering if there is an alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the `stringr` package to replace pipes in all strings between `>` and the next `<` using `>[^<]+<`.  I also added `[^"]` to avoid replacing pipes between tags like `<taskxml>"|"<?xml`

```
x <- 'this|"<is>"|"<a>"|"<test>1|2|3</test>"'
str_replace_all( x, '>[^"][^<]+<', function(x) gsub("\\|", " ", x) )
[1] "this|\"<is>\"|\"<a>\"|\"<test>1 2 3</test>\""
```

Comment: This is working perfectly but it is somehow also removing the pipe between `<taskxml>"|"<?xml`. So, it is squeezing TASK_ML_DATA and SCORE_XML_DATA into one.

Comment: Check and make sure it's a double quote in the file and not something else since this seems to work? `str_replace_all('<taskxml>"|"<?xml', '>[^"][^<]+<', function(x) gsub("\\|", " ", x))`.

Comment: This is the output I'm getting on the real data: Original text file (after reading into R using readLines) - `</taskxml></task></tasks>\"|\"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><scores` .                                  After applying string replacement code - `</taskxml></task></tasks>\" \"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><scores`

Comment: That does not remove the pipe for me.   Maybe try `str_replace_all(x, '>[^\\p{quotation mark}][^<]+<', function(x) gsub("\\|", " ", x))`